# Limits, sequences and integral envolving cosine and sine.

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $I_n(x) = \displaystyle \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos(xt) \cos^ntdt$. Show that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{I_n(x)}{I_n(0)}= 1$.

I am making a undergraduate paper and I need to prove that limit, I have searched a solution on Internet but I didn't get it. I will put the solution here and I hope you help me.

\begin{equation*}
    |I_n(0) - I_n(x)| = \left| \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (1 - \cos xt) cos^n t dt \right|
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    \leq \frac{1}{2}x^2 \displaystyle \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} t^2 \cos^n t dt
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\leq \frac{1}{2}x^2 \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} t \cos^{n-1}t  \sin t  dt
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
= \frac{1}{n} I_n(0).
\end{equation*}

Then, $\lim \vert I_n(0) - I_n(x) \vert $ goes to zero. Thus $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {I_n(x)}{I_n(0)}=1.$

Ok, from second to third step I guess, fixing $x$ $\vert (1 - \cos xt) \vert \leq \vert x^2t^2 \vert$ and from third to fourth he used $t \leq \tan t$, but how he arrived in $\frac{1}{2}x^2 \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} t \cos^{n-1}t  \sin t  dt = \frac{1}{n}I_n(0)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By integration by parts
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2} t \sin(t)\cos^{n-1}(t)\,dt =\left[-\frac{t}{n}\cos^{n}(t)\right]_{0}^{\pi/2}+\frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^n(t)\,dt $$
so your chain of inequalities proves
$$ \frac{|I_n(x)-I_n(0)|}{I_n(0)}\leq \frac{x^2}{2n} $$
which is enough to deduce that the limit of the LHS as $n\to +\infty$ is zero ($I_n(0)$ is obviously positive).

Comment: Ok, it's very simple, but I have a question. $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} |I_n(0) - I_n(x)| = 0$ implies  $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to 0} \frac{I_n(x)}{I_n(0)}=1$???

Comment: @user638057: no, as previously remarked by amsmath in the comments. The difference between $\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{n^2}$ goes to zero, the ratio does not go to $1$.

Comment: then which this results I can't say that $\displaystyle \lim \frac{I_n(x)}{I_n(0)}=1??$

Comment: Your chain of inequalities give that $\frac{I_n(x)-I_n(0)}{I_n(0)}\to 0$ (much stronger than $I_n(x)-I_n(0)\to 0$), so $\frac{I_n(x)}{I_n(0)}\to 1$.

Comment: Obvious, thank you